# Odd color split on Carnival light video

Tags: color

[image]

Don't know what is going on. This is a screenshot of a carnival ride and there seems to be color on the top and bottom of the video but not in the middle? I'm using an S8+.

Comment: Welcome to photo.stackexchange. I agree with your description of the screenshot. Can you edit your post to provide more information about the situation? Then, what is your question?

Comment: Is this something you shot?  The color is messed up on the bottom too.  It honestly looks like issues associated with tracking loss on a VHS tape and there seems to be interlacing issues on the most corrupt part, but that only makes sense if this is a video you found somewhere, not if it is something you shot.